# Maven not showing up in Eclipse (Kepler) even after m2e install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-ee-7

I've seen that others have had this problem where Maven doesn't show up for them in Eclipse after installing the m2e plugin, but most of the solutions seem to suggest doing something like "Configure>Convert to Maven." But Maven is not showing up for me in the Configure list, nor is it showing up in Console>Open Console or the File>New list.  I see some solutions refer to editing the project's classpath, but I don't have a clear understanding of how to do that. I'm trying to begin working through a book on Java EE7, and it uses Maven in the examples. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you restarted eclipse after installing m2e? Have you tried  `File > New > Other...` and checked whether is there a `Maven` folder?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted Eclipse after installing.  When I go to File>New>Other, Maven is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Check the .log file in the .metadata folder in your workspace folder.  Delete the .log file and then restart Eclipse using the -clean option.  If maven doesn't appear in the UI the look at the .log file for hints of why maven couldn't be loaded.

Comment: OK, I did what you suggested.  When Maven still didn't show up, I checked the log file.  The log file says "The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Users\Kyle Walker\AppData\Local\Temp\eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi"  Any ideas?

Comment: The storage area is in a temp directory, so try deleting that whole temp directory manually.  If the problem persists, it might have something to do with incompatible java compile levels.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're saying it's OK to delete the entire Temp folder and everything in it, whether it's related to eclipse or not?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to download Eclipse Java EE (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr)? It already has Maven installed

Comment: I updated Eclipse to include the Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools. I'm looking at my Eclipse Installation Details, and I see Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools, but I don't see Maven anywhere.

Comment: I meant http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr

Comment: Yes, looking up at the top of my Eclipse window, it says "Java EE-Eclipse".

Comment: What OS, what Eclipse (x86/x64)?

Comment: Windows 7 x64, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers,Version: Kepler Release, Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: Is Eclipse 32 bit, or 64? What JDK do you use?

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.7.  The closest I can tell about Eclipse is that it keeps mentioning "86_64" in the Installation Details.  Not sure where else to look for that. (I've got to step out of the house for a while and will check back in this evening.)  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I just uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse. Not sure what was causing the problem in the first place, but this seems to have done the trick. I made sure to install the Java EE version of Eclipse and Maven is showing up now.

Answer (score 0):

First, please ensure that m2e is correctly install. To test this, just right click on the project and you should be able to see 'Maven' in the context menu.

If it is showing, just choose 'Update project config'; as soon as this is updated, the m2e recognizes and build the project as maven.

After that, please check if project property-> build path -> lib tab shows maven dependency along with default JRE in the library path.

Comment: When right-click project, Maven doesn't show up anywhere. But when I try to install m2e using Help>Install New Software using http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases, it says that "All items are installed."

Comment: Ok, it means your installation is somehow still not working or the project is still not getting recognized as a maven project. One thing I could suggest here that to use different flavor of Eclipse. I am using STS (Spring Tool Suite, another open IDE based on eclipse) and this is rich in plugins. If you need I could share my version of STS, which is all set with configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically permission problem if u are using linux. Delete the eclipse folder and workspace directory(/home/user/workspace). Extract the eclipse again using root. Give full permission to eclipse folder and launch eclipse using root. then install maven plugin from marketplace or installNewSoftware page. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I discovered that, oddly enough, closing and reopening Eclipse is **NOT** the same thing as "restarting" Eclipse.  When it asks if you want to restart now either choose Yes or choose Restart from the File menu.