# Maven is not showing in Eclipse Luna, After Migrating to Jdk8 to Jdk7

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, maven-plugin, jdk1.7

To fix some issues related to an old project, I migrated Jdk8 to Jdk7 and now I'm unable to find Maven in my Eclipse Luna.

I have checked some previous post like, [Maven not showing up in Eclipse (Kepler) even after m2e install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687621/maven-not-showing-up-in-eclipse-kepler-even-after-m2e-install).

But those solutions are not fixing my problem. I have another Eclipse Mars Editor, in that I can able to see Maven.

My Environment is: Ubuntu 32bit
user@user:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
user@user:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_67

Comment: Maven inside Eclipse is built-in. Every new Eclipse package now included embed Maven. You also use external Maven.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you @DoNhuVy , but it is not visible now in editor.  On terminal, I can see maven version.